# Textfields and values with a value of 0 get blanked out if stepped forward/backwards

Tags: forms, 7

I have a multipage form programmed with the drupal FAPI having in total 3 pages of fields consisting of textfields, textareas and radios, the form can be stepped forwards and backwards.

On page 2 of the form i have a few textfields where the user needs to enter numeric values. If these fields are not applicable, the user is asked to enter a **0**.

The problem I have now if the user fills out that page No. 2, fills in a few **0** in these textfields and steps forwards/backwards, and afterwards steps back to that very page, the fields formerly filled with **0** are blank.

I really have no clue how to solve that as I need to use numeric values.

I now could set the default value to **0** instead of an empty value, but that would force the initial form to have already a **0** set. I do not want to solve it like this.

I have the feeling that the **0** is probably treated as a **NULL** (but actually in PHP **0** and **NULL** are different), but I am not sure. Dumping out the form array shows that indeed that 0 values are blank.

A textfield looks like this:

```
$form['t_2_1_2'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('... label text ...'),
    '#description' => ' ... desc. text ...',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => !empty($form_state['values']['t_2_1_2']) ?
        $form_state['values']['t_2_1_2'] : '',
);
```

The structure of the entire form handling is very much based on the drupal multipage form example in the `drupal form examples` package!

Is there any way how I can solve that issue, that a value of **0** persists in the form, even stepping forward/backward?

I already tried to investigate similar problems, and found one where where the suggestion was to prepend a space to the 0 value, but that is a hack and I do not / can not use that as such!

Any hints are greatly appreciated, as I am sitting on this problem too long now and my time is running out to solve that issue. Thanks in advance for your hints!

**Update:** As nobody could help me here and my time is running, I solved the problem by using an '**x**' instead of the '**0**' value, changed the validation to check for either a numeric value or an '**x**'. Now the values all persist in the form fields, when I jump backwards/forwards in that multipage form. If the user used '**x**', the value will be converted into an '**0**' value in the submit handler because the data is stored into mysql, and these fields are of type integer. At least a way I can live with.

Comment: Nobody out there having an idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply allow users leave the field empty and convert any empty “numeric” fields to a '0' in your submit handler. That might be a better user experience since it would save users the trouble of having to enter *any* values in those fields.